# Find average of dynamic arraylist with decimal and integer values java

Tags: java, arraylist, arrays

I am using `JSONArray` for saving dynamic values,the values can be integer or double values,I need to find average and median for those values in `JSONArray`,for that I am saving the values in `arraylist` and trying  to find average,since the list consist of integer or double values it is showing Classcast exception.Please give me solution for finding average and median for arraylist values(Integer or double values).I have tried with code below but it looping double the array size....

```
for (Object o : list) {
            if (o.getClass().equals(Integer.class)) {
                handleint(list);
            }
            else if (o.getClass().equals(Double.class)) {
                handledouble(list);
            }

        }


for(Object obj: list){
           if(obj instanceof Double)
           {
           sum1 = sum1 + ((Double) obj).doubleValue();
             average = sum1 / list.size();
}
else if(obj instanceof Integer)
           {
          sum1 = sum1 + ((Double) obj).doubleValue();
             average = sum1 / list.size();
}
}
```

Comment: what `handleint` and `handledouble` do? share complete code. Are you using Raw type of List?

Comment: yes i am using raw list,inside handleint method i have added the list values and dive the values by array size

Comment: I don't think that you need a separate list for calculating average because you can do it while saving values in list from JSONArray.

Comment: I am saving the values in linked hashset and i am using list to find the average values

Comment: I tried with your code, i am getting correct values..Thank you

Comment: You have asked 8 questions and none of accepted.

Answer (score 0):

How to find average:
Add up all elements in the Arraylist

divide by the ArrayList's size

How to find median:
Use Collections.sort() on the ArrayList to sort it

get the element at the middle of the ArrayList (ArrayList's size/2)

Answer (score 0):

Use `instanceof` operator instead of using `Class.equals()` that is better way.

Use single `instanceof` for `Number` that is super class of `Integer` and `Double`.

Here is sample code:

```
double total=0;
int count=0;

for(Object obj:list){
    if(obj instanceof Number){
        total+=((Number)obj).doubleValue();
        count++;
    }
}

double average=total/count;
```

Comment: I have tried with inatance of but again not getting correct values